# Unable to create a Python package for pip

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

I have been unsuccessful in creating a Python package distribution. I have followed the instructions in https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/ and this is what happens. For e.g. if I create the necessary files and folders as required

```
first/
   first/
     __init__.py
     setup.py
     LICENSE
     README.md
     myfirst.py
```

I have made the package name as 'first' in setup.py

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

    setuptools.setup(
        name="tvg11",
        version="0.0.1",
        author="Ganesh",
        author_email="tvganesh.85@gmail.com",
        description="A small example package",
        long_description=long_description,
        long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
        url="https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject",
        packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
        classifiers=[
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
            "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
            "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        ],
    )
```

Then I run the commands

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
python -m twine upload --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ dist/*
```

which creates `dist/`, `build/` and `first.egg-info`.

Now I find that if I am in the same directory and do a

```
pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ first
```

Then I find that this creates a new folder **pycache** with the compiled code and I am able to do `import first`

```
first/
  first/
    __pycache__     # new!
    build/
    dist/
    first.egg.info
    __init__.py
    setup.py
    LICENSE
    README.md
    myfirst.py
```

However, if I am in any other folder other the root folder 'first/first' and I do a

```
pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ first
```

I get a 'Successfully installed' but when I invoke python and do an `import first` I get `ModuleNotFoundError` "No module 'first'".

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. The instructions were so simple.

Comment: Please show your full setup script. Looks like the `first` package is not bundled. Also, run `pip show -f first` and verify all files are listed.

Comment: @hoefling 'pip show -f first'gives nothng. Since I had done a 'pip install tiwne' earler, when I checked 'pip -f show twine' I get a list of all files - .py,.pyc, LICENSE etc. Yes it looks like I am missing some step  in 'bundling' the package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have looked interactively in test.pypi.org ...

You would have immediately noticed that your own project in not known as `first` but as `tvg11`. What matters is the name and version number inside the `setup.py` file and not the folder name.

But the real cause is that you have put the files of the package at same level as the `setup.py` file and used `packages=setuptools.find_packages()`. So as you have no packages below `setup.py`, `find_packages` found nothing, and you have built and interesting package containing little more than `setup.py` and `README.md`.

How to fix:

First you should build a more common structure for your package:

```
  - first
    - setup.py
    - LICENSE
    - README.md

    - first
        - __init__.py
        - myfirst.py
```

That way `find_package` will find the content of the `first` subfolder as the source for the `tvg11` package.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked! Strange the example given in https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/ was not clear at all. Appreciate it.